# Java Variables not updating on timer

Tags: java, actionlistener

I am trying to create a moving object with incrementing x and y coordinates, by setting up a timer in the movingGame class, firing an actionlistener in a different class which in turn runs a method in the original class, which runs the code to increment the x and y variables, and, for checking the values, prints out x and y. However, x and y don't go up, as if the result wasn't recorded. If I increment them before printing results, it is one, showing it increased properly from *its original value*. If I increment after printing the value, it will show no difference in value. Here is my code:

movingGame class:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class movingGame extends JFrame {

    public int x;
    public int y;

    void moving() {
        Timer timer = new Timer(100,new ActionPerformer());
        timer.start(); 
    }

    public void timeToDraw() {
        //This is where it is supposed to increment.
        x++;
        y++;
        System.out.println("y: "+y);
        System.out.println("x: "+x);
        //If I put x++ and y++ here, it would give a value of 0.
    };

    public static void main(String[] args){
        movingGame d = new movingGame();
        d.setVisible(true);
        d.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        d.setSize(1000, 666);
        d.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
        d.moving();
    };
}
```

The ActionPerformer class:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class ActionPerformer implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        movingGame m = new movingGame();
        m.timeToDraw();
    }
}
```

In summary my problem is that after running the method, the x and y values remain unchanged, and changes are only shown inside the method, but only in the particular run. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The convention is to capitalise the names  of classes in Java. So in this case, `movingGame` should be `MovingGame`, just like it's `ActionPerformer`, `ActionListener`, `ActionEvent`, `JFrame`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a new MovingGame in the `actionPerformed()` method. Instead, you should pass a reference to the game created in your `main` Method. Something along the lines

```
public class ActionPerformer implements ActionListener {
    private movingGame game;

    public ActionPerformer(movingGame mg) {
        this.game = mg;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        this.game.timeToDraw();
    }
}
```

and then

```
Timer timer = new Timer(100, new ActionPerformer(this));
```

Comment: don't forget to mention that you also need to tell the timer not to 'condense' the invocations....

Comment: @AmirAfghani that's right, so a `timer.setCoalesce(false)` would stop the timer from executing only one event in the case multiple events queued up to be fired. OP can read more here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html#setCoalesce(boolean)

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new `MovingGame` object every time an action is performed. Try creating the object outside of the `actionPerformed` method